# how to create website using Django

Tags: django, apache, nginx, web, hosting

I have one Django App. I want to get this app on World Wide Web.
Can anyone please help me with steps.
Like Some server addition(e.g. Apache or Nginx),Configuration of server,Integrating with Django,Web Hosting,etc.

Thanks

Comment: You mean you need to deploy your app? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/

Answer (score 0):

This at this link you will find a tutorial that helps you to deploy your app with NGINX
http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html

simple and fast

Answer (score 0):

In regards to hosting, you will have to get a domain name (unless you want to connect to your web page via IP address).

If you want to host your own web page from your server you will also have to set up your router to forward traffic to your server's IP. Having a static IP from your internet provider is preferable and also set your machine to have a static IP so you don't have problems with routing.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the hassle of setting up a server environment all by yourself, you can also choose a PaaS provider like Heroku which supports Django applications out of the box. Hosting will cost more, but you will save time deploying your apps.